# Saving each new dataframe created inside a for-loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe, overriding, mask

I wrote a function that iterates over the files in a folder and selects certain data. The .csv files look like this:

```
Timestamp  Value         Result    
00-00-10   34567          1.0  
00-00-20   45425     
00-00-30   46773          0.0  
00-00-40   64567   
00-00-50   25665          1.0  
00-01-00   25678  
00-01-10   84358 
00-01-20   76869          0.0
00-01-30   95830          
00-01-40   87890        
00-01-50   99537            
00-02-00   85957          1.0
00-02-10   58840
```

They are saved in the path `C:/Users/me/Desktop/myfolder/data` and I wrote the code in `C:/Users/me/Desktop/myfolder`. The function (after @Daniel R 's suggestion):

```
PATH = os.getcwd()+'\DATA\\'
def my_function(SourceFolder):
for i, file_path in enumerate(os.listdir(PATH)):
    df = pd.read_csv(PATH+file_path)
    mask = (
    (df.Result == 1) 
    | (df.Result.ffill() == 1)
    | ((df.Result.ffill() == 0) 
       & (df.groupby((df.Result.ffill() != df.Result.ffill().shift()).cumsum()).Result.transform('size') <= 100))
   )
    df = mask[df]  
    df = df.to_csv(PATH+'df_{}.csv'.format(i))
```

My initial question was: How do I save each `df[mask]` to `NewFolder` without overriding the data? The code above throws `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Result'.`

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-14c0dbaf5ace> in <module>()
----> 1 retrieve_data('C:/Users/me/Desktop/myfolder/DATA/*.csv')

<ipython-input-2-ba68702431ca> in my_function(SourceFolder)
      6         (df.Result == 1)
      7         | (df.Result.ffill() == 1)
----> 8         | ((df.Result.ffill() == 0) 
      9            & (df.groupby((df.Result.ffill() != df.Result.ffill().shift()).cumsum()).Result.transform('size') <= 100)))
     10         df = df[mask]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4370             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   4371                 return self[name]
-> 4372             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   4373 
   4374     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Result'
```

Comment: I assume this dataframe is pandas dataframe. You could use [pandas.dataframe.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: retrieve_data() was not mentioned earlier, and its code is not present. We'll skip it for now. One of your dataframes most likely lacks the Result column, or is it not labeled with the string 'Result'. Add a `print(df.columns)` statement immediately after `df = pd.read_csv(PATH+file_path)`, if it is feasible to check by hand. If not, you may have to `assert` that all dataframes have the expected list of columns. Also, I just noticed that the `mask` searches for integers, not floats. Although this is not what throws the error, you may still want to fix it.

Comment: @DanielR. Sorry, that was the name of the function used in my script, I forgot to change it to the mock function I posted here. It printed only `Index(['timestamp;Value;Result'], dtype='object')`, does that mean that it doesn't even identify the columns?

Comment: replace `df = pd.read_csv(PATH+file_path)` with `df = pd.read_csv(PATH+file_path, sep=';')`, see if it works. By default pandas parses the csv on `','`, unless you specify the `sep` parameter. From your mock dataframe it was not possible to determine the separator used in the csv files.

Comment: @DanielR. I got the same error after a while. In the meantime it created all the new files, but in a really messy way, i.e. everything is separated by commas when I open it in Excel (column names, values etc.)

Comment: The csv files are exactly [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), files with Comma Separated Values :) This means that the code is working as intended. If you need to use Excel on them, rather than pandas, you must tell Excel to open them as csv files rather than xls files, but this is unfortunately getting outside of the scopes of the question, and of Python programming.

Comment: @DanielR. Indeed, it was just a matter of importing external data and selecting the comma delimiter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe has a structure that satisfies the requirements for a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Let '\DATA\\' be the directory where you keep your csv files, as a subdirectory of .getcwd()
PATH = os.getcwd()+'\DATA\\'
def my_function(source_folder):
    for i, file_path in enumerate(os.listdir(PATH)):
        df = pd.read_csv(PATH+file_path)   # Use read_csv here, not DataFrame.
                              # You are still working with a filepath, not a dictionary.
        mask = ( (df.Result == 1) | (df.Result.ffill() == 1) |
                 ((df.Result.ffill() == 0) &
                 (df.groupby((df.Result.ffill() !=
                  df.Result.ffill().shift()).cumsum()).Result.transform('size') <= 100))
                 )
        df = df[mask]
        df = df.to_csv(PATH+'df_{}.csv'.format(i))
```

You should provide a sample of the data you are working on when asking question similar to this one, as a general rule. The answers received may not work for you otherwise. Please update the question with a sample of a dataframe/csv file, and a mock content of the directory, so I can update this answer.

If srcPath is different from os.getcwd() you may have to compute the full path, or the path relative to .getcwd(), before iterating on the files.

Also, the call to list() above may not be necessary, test the code with or without it.

Lastly, why are you requiring two variables as inputs for my_function()?
As far as I can see there is only one variable required, which is srcPath called in .glob(), and this is not a variable passed to the function so it must be a global variable.

**EDIT:** I have updated the code above on the basis of the modifications to the original questions, and the comments to this post down below.

**EDIT 2:** Turns out that your call to the glob.glob() did not produce what you wanted. See the updated code.

Comment: Thank you, I added the rest. The mask works for an individual file, but when I apply the function to `C:/Users/me/Desktop/myfolder/data/*.csv` an error appears.

Comment: You cannot unfortunately call `(df.Result == 1)` inside the mask = statement, because you have not yet created a pandas dataframe. This is done by the df = pd.DataFrame(df) instruction that follows the mask statement. It should not work though, because you must call pd.read_csv() on the filepath as suggested in the example above. You may want, in case it confuses you, to replace the iterating variable `df` in the `for` statement with `file` or something similar, to avoid misunderstanding. Until you call pd.DataFrame() you are still working with a filepath, not a dataframe. EDIT: check the code

Comment: Thank you, I understand the cause of the error, but I keep getting the same Attribute Error. `df = pd.DataFrame(file_path)` doesn't work since the DataFrame constructor is not properly called.

Comment: Careful: you must use `df = pd.read_csv(file_path)` on the path to the csv file, as shown in the code above, not `df = pd.DataFrame(file_path)`. If you want to use pd.DataFrame() to instantiate the dataframe, you must pass a dictionary, not a filepath, to the constructor.

Comment: I'm sorry, my comment was confusing, I meant to say that after using `df = pd.read_csv(file_path)` I kept getting the attribute error.

Comment: There was an error in the call to enumerate(glob.glob()). The updated answer fixes it.

Comment: Now I'm getting `OSError: Initializing from file failed`, and I added `engine = 'python'` inside `pd.read_csv`, but I get `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\myfolder\\DATA\\.ipynb_checkpoints'`. I checked the data in the documents and there isn't any problem with the content.

Comment: Ok do this: Save the notebook. Take your Jupyter notebook out of the DATA folder and back into myfolder. Delete .ipynb_checkpoints folder from DATA. Take all your csv files, and put them into the DATA folder. Do not add anything else in the DATA folder. Run the script. Does it work?

Comment: There is nothing else apart from the .csv files in `DATA`, and the notebook is saved in `myfolder` (which also contains the folder `DATA`). I no longer get the previous error, but instead the `AttributeError` again.

Comment: Please post here the full traceback of the AttributeError